# Is it possible to somehow change the format of the received date?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Angular Material has such an [example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/baxjjrdgpal?file=app%2Fdatepicker-events-example.html). Using DatePicker select the date and below under the component, we get this result:

Example:

> Tue Oct 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0500

Is it possible to change this result to the date format `YYYY-MM-DD`? As if using `input` `type = "date"`.

Do not offer this option:

```
<div *ngFor="let e of events">{{e | date}}</div>
```

Because the date does not need to be displayed. The date just needs to be sent to the server.

Comment: Downvoting as no research done by the user, could've searched it easily on the internet, there are already 100's of example available for the same.

Comment: @Hemendra If there are hundreds of examples, add at least one

Comment: I suggest you should read on how to ask a question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I think yes, try to check this implementation:

https://medium.com/@amandeepkochhar/angular-material-datepicker-set-custom-date-in-dd-mm-yyyy-format-5c0f4340e57

Comment: Using this example, this error occurs: `Cannot read property 'TRIDENT' of undefined`

Comment: it's possible that you have "MAT_DATE_LOCALE" in your providers? In this case you must remove it and it will be works fine.

Comment: In general, this is not at all what I wanted, like the previous answers. This changes the date format in the component itself, but  need a date format that is used when sending it to the server. I already wrote that when you select a date below the component, a value will be displayed that displays the format of the date for sending. It looks something like this: `change: Tue Oct 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT + 0500`

Answer (score 0):

**Angular Date Formate**
yes you can change formate of date

```
“short” – equivalent to “M/d/yy h:mm a”;
“medium” – equivalent to “MMM d, y h:mm:ss a”;
“shortDate” – equivalent to “M/d/yy” (5/7/19);
“mediumDate” – equivalent to “MMM d, y” (May 7, 2019);
“longDate” – equivalent to “MMMM d, y” (May 7, 2019);
“fullDate” – equivalent to “EEEE, MMMM d, y” (Tuesday, May 7, 2019);
“shortTime” – equivalent to “h:mm a” (2:35 AM);
“mediumTime” – equivalent to “h:mm:ss a” (2:35:05 AM);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<div *ngFor="let e of events">{{e | date: 'short'}}</div> // output: 10/7/19
<div *ngFor="let e of events">{{e | date: 'medium'}}</div> // output: Oct 7, 2019 etc…
```